# geom_text only shows when I zoom on plot; won't show in viewer or when saved to file

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add text to a faceted ggplot. I have done so by adding a column to the original data file with the text I want to plot and then add it via geom_text as specified in a variety of other posts on SO. However, the text only shows up when I zoom in on the plot in RStudio - it does not show up in the plot viewer panel OR, more importantly, when I try and save the plot to a pdf or png file.

I have attempted to use annotate rather than geom_text and also to modify the ggsave function in a variety of ways (e.g. by adding device to the call and changing the size of the format). I've attempted changing the size of the geom_text, but that did not seem to work either. There is likely some simple problem, but I cannot see it.

```
library(tidyverse)

###Creates the df I"m using 

explanations <- tribble(
  ~study, ~model, ~comparison, ~ame, ~se, ~p, ~yax, ~fstat, 
  "Study 1", "Co-Partisans", "By Itself",  0.16043, 0.02521, 0.001, "Overall Effects", "",
  "Study 1", "Co-Partisans", "With Counter",  -0.04861, 0.02011, 0.01588, 
      "Overall Effects", "Sig diff from Explanation, p < 0.001", 
  "Study 1", "Co-Partisans", "With Counter (High Credibility)",  -0.07990, 0.02103, 0.000157, 
  "Overall Effects", "Sig diff from Explanation, p < 0.001",
  "Study 1", "Co-Partisans", "With Counter (Low Credibility)",  0.02350, 0.02550, 0.357079,
  "Overall Effects", "Sig diff from Explanation, p < 0.05",
  "Study 2", "Co-Partisans", "By Itself", 0.01168, 0.01589, 0.46261, "Overall Effects", "", 
  "Study 2", "Co-Partisans", "With Counter", -0.03962, 0.01387, 0.00439,"Overall Effects", 
  "Sig diff from Explanation, p < 0.001",
  "Study 2", "Co-Partisans", "With Counter (High Credibility)",  -0.05847, 0.01602, 0.000282,
  "Overall Effects", "Sig diff from Explanation, p < 0.001",
  "Study 2", "Co-Partisans", "With Counter (Low Credibility)",      -0.02062, 0.01606, 0.199389,
  "Overall Effects", "Sig diff from Explanation, p < 0.05")

###Plots the figure
library(ggstance)

explanations %>%
  tbl_df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, 
             linetype=2) +
  geom_pointrangeh(aes(y=yax, x=ame, xmin=ame-(1.96*se), xmax=ame+(1.96*se))) + 
  scale_y_discrete(
    breaks = explanations$yax %>%
      levels, 
    labels = explanations$yax %>%
      levels %>%
      str_to_title
  ) + 
  facet_grid(comparison ~ study, 
             labeller = label_wrap_gen(width=13), 
             switch = "y") + 
  theme_minimal(20) + 
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(color="grey96", fill = "grey96"), 
        strip.background = element_rect(color="grey96", fill="grey96"),
        panel.grid=element_blank() ,
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold"), 
        strip.text.y = element_text(angle=180), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)
  ) + 
  labs(title = "Effect of Explanation \nwith and without Counters" , 
       y=NULL, x="Marginal Effect \nPositive = The Explantion 'Works'") + 
  geom_text(data = explanations, aes(x=-Inf, y=-Inf, label=fstat, 
                hjust = -1.90,
                vjust = -5.5))

ggsave("figure.png", height=6, width=8)
```

The plot should have the "fstat" text (e.g. "Sig diff from ...") displayed on all of the facets save the top two. It does indeed do so...but only when I look at the figure via the zoom function on RStudio. The saved output, though, does not print the "Sig diff..." text on the facets. Where am I going wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When the plot is displayed in yours "Plots" tab, click on "Zoom" button. Then try to make window smaller and bigger and see what happens with text ;)

Comment: Ah, interesting. That does influence the appearance of the text (e.g. it disappears if too small). I just tried increasing the size of the pdf as well (e.g. height=10, width=12 rather than 8 and 10) and now the text is starting to peek into the image. Is there anyway to have the text show up without blowing up the image to monstrous sizes? I'm eventually putting the figure into a Beamer presentation, so perhaps the inlcudegraphics command there will take care of that...

Comment: Try with some on-screen ruler :D Set "Plot" pane to desired size. Then manipulate `geom_text`s params to make text visible, and finally save it with `ggsave` without specifying `width` and `height` parameters, so it will take your's "Plot" pane dimensions. I know it sounds stupid ;D But I was looking a lot in the internet for the solution of this problem and didn't find any.